# Присваивание значения переменной - Scanner несколько раз

Tags: java, исключения, scanner

Есть сканер Int чисел. С помощью try catch обрабатываю ошибку того, что это не число типа Int, но при вводе чего-то другого, кроме целого числа выдается исключение

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at Learn.main(Learn.java:27)
```

Код:

```
int a;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Input there some int number of the count of variables \n");
try {
    System.out.println("STARTUEMBLYAD");
    a = in.nextInt();
}
catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("Error! Please, input valid number: 1,2,3, ...");
}
finally {
    if (a != 0) {
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" + a);
    } else in.nextInt();
}
in.close();
```

27 строка - `else in.nextInt();`

Что неправильно я использую в сканере? Как сделать так, чтобы при вводе не целого числа был запрос на повторный ввод числа (чтобы можно было ещё раз ввести что-либо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Измените на `in.nextLine()`. А затем попробуйте преобразовать к `int`(если не получится - кинет ошибку). У вас не получается потому, что `in.nextInt()` ищет следующее целое число - остальное он игнорирует. Вам нужно строку читать.

```
a = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
```

И да - `Integer.parseInt()` кидает NumberFormatException, если не получается преобразовать. Замените на `catch(NumberFormatException e)`
А чтобы повторно просилось - оберните в блок `while(true)`. Добавьте `break` в конце блока `try`(мы уверены, что все прошло удачно).